# Trying to add NixOS to my Fedora grub

Tags: fedora, grub2, nixos

I'm trying out NixOS and want to add it to the Grub menu from my fedora installation, but I can't figure out how to do that. I have Fedora and NixOS on the same drive, but different partitions and I also have Windows on a complete different drive.
When I run `sudo grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg` I get this:

```
Generating grub configuration file ...
find: '/run/media/edgar/NIX': No such file or directory
find: 'BOOT/EFI': No such file or directory
Found NixOS 23.05 (Stoat) (23.05) on /dev/nvme2n1p5
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/sda2@/efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings ...
done
```

So my NixOS install is recognized, but when I reboot I get no new grub entry.

I figured I might need to add an entry manually, but when I add

```
    menuentry "NixOS" {
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod search_fs_uuid
    insmod chain
    search --fs-uuid --set=root A1FE-673E
    chainloader /EFI/BOOT/BOOTX64.EFI
}
```

to `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` it tells me no such directory is found, so I'm doing something wrong, but I'm not quite sure what.

Any help would be appreciated!